# Writing an IntelliJ plugin to check @see references

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

In our in-house java framework we are calling methods remotely using RMI, in short it looks like this:

**Server:**

```
public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod(String param1, String param2) { ... }
}
```

**Client:**

```
/**
 * @see myPackage.MyClass.class#myMethod(String, String)
**/
invoke(MyClass.class, "myMethod", "param1", "param2");
```

We made it a coding rule to document all remote calls with an `@see`.

**Risk:** Of course, when you change the method signature, then the link can be broken, and that would result in a bug, which will only be detected at runtime.

For this reason **we are planning to write our own IntelliJ plugin**, which should be triggered from the menu (during development), to scan the code for broken or missing links.

**My concerns:**

- We have no experience in writing IntelliJ plugins. Will it be possible to write this plugin, or is it extremely hard (nearly impossible) to do so ?
- Maybe we are reinventing something that already exists.

Comment: You can do this easily with a plugin, but I wonder if the IDE is the right place to check this. Maybe a build system plugin (Maven, or whatever) would make more sense?  If the IntelliJ plugin has to be manually triggered, that's a fragile test; you could always make it a live inspection, but you would need to consider the overhead.  How often do your remote targets change?

Comment: Have you  tried the *Java | Javadoc issues | Declaration has problems in Javadoc references* inspection?

Comment: @Steve Chaloner We build using ant scripts. I figured a plugin on build-script level would not have the same tools to actually interpret the code. I was hoping that an intellij plugin would have easier access to interpreting the meaning of the written java code.

Comment: @bvdb IntelliJ's PSI code is open-sourced as Apache 2, so you can use it to build your Ant plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. you can do it by observing editor event. I can help you if you can explain your requirement from the plugin.

refer http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/annotator.html
you can do it with annotator